# Set up multiple laravel apps on nginx server

Tags: laravel, nginx, configuration-files, vps

I want to create a config file on my nginx vps to handle 2 laravel apps. I don’t own any domain name.

What I want is:

http://my_ip/app1 will resolve to the first app
http://my_ip/app2 will resolve to the second app

and if anyone tries to access the root http://my_ip/ to show a 503 or a custom html file.

Comment: been looking around the web, can't find anything useful.... did you have any luck resolving this?

Comment: I used different ports on the server blocks. I will post my nginx config file at the end of the day!

Comment: awesome, would be cool if you find time for that. thanks.